# Initiating session issue

Tags: wcf

Let's consider this chat service:(the entire application may be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWPFChat.aspx))

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IChatCallback))]
interface IChat
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    string[] Join(string name);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Say(string msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Whisper(string to, string msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Leave();
}
```

The Join method initiates a session and the Leave method ends it.
Let's say i want to authenticate my users, create a service IAuth let's say with 2 methods Login and Logout. How should i initiate and terminate the session(because from what i've read this application requires a session) in this case, having different services?
PS: i am new to wcf so any piece of advice helps. Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to authenticate user with credentials or you want to be able to start or end a session?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initiate or terminate session (although technically it is possible) by yourself. WCF will do that for you. It will initiate sessions once `Join` will be called and will terminate session once `Leave` will be called.

Comment: It will do because there is IsInitiating=true on Join and IsTerminating=true on Leave, but consider some other severice that allows user to make other stuff..i must also use IsInitiating=true on Login and IsTerminating=true on Logout?

Comment: It depends from the service logic. Do you really want to allow to have several initiation points. I mean is it OK for you that and Login and Join will initiate a session. May be you need to review it ...